# Django Queryset Unit Test

Tags: django, unit-testing

I am new to Unit testing as a whole and am wondering how to write a unit test for the following function.

```
from poll.models import Poll
def total():
    all_polls = Poll.objects.all()
    return all_polls.count()
```

Ideally, what should I be testing for in the function above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much point in testing this particular function as it doesn't do anything very useful. But, since you're using it as an example, the principle is to set up the system with some sample data, then check the function returns what you're expecting. So, in this case, your test could create two Poll objects, then assert that the function returns the value 2.

You might also want to check edge cases: the only one I can think of in this case is that it doesn't crash when there are no Polls at all. So, before inserting your two Polls, you could call the function and test it returns 0; then, add the two instances and check for the return value 2.

Generally, though, you should avoid testing Django's own functionality: that is well covered in Django's own unit tests. in cases like this where your function does nothing other than call built-in methods, there's really no point in checking that the `count()` function returns two because we already know it will.